# Universities recommandations and choices

Tags: graduate-school, masters, university, bachelor

I'm a tunisian student, i have a dream to persuit masters educations in a better university in Europe, USA, UK or Canada. I have a Bachelor degree (Licentiate, BAC+3) in computer science and multimedia field and i speak and write three languages fluently(Arabic-Frensh-English).
I would like to know if a have enough chance to reach it and what to do?
Any recommandations will be helpfull.
Thank's

Comment: So-called "shopping questions", which yours might be, are off-topic here. Even if it were ok to ask about your chances to be admitted, this depends on all kind of factors you didn't mention (e.g., GPA, your school's ranking and who you worked with there, letters of recommendation, where you apply). If you click/search the tags "graduate school" or "admission"/"graduate admission" though, you might find several question that might help you.

Comment: this is all what i ask about!! "what should i mention?" and specially "What to do?" i dont mean to advertize anything or "Shopping".

Comment: That's just a term: it means "asking which school to choose", etc. Have a look at the help center, and you'll see it there. That said, click the tags I mentioned, and I think you'll find some old questions that might help. Being "a Tunesian student" certainly won't disqualify you - one of the smartest researchers I knew in France was.